How to cross out an entire column with dense diagonal lines?
I'm trying to obtain such a picture in Tikz: (the dots are irrelevant)

I know I can already create the grid using
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) grid (6, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

But how can I cross out the columns in such a dense way?

Please post a normal and complete and runable example...

Is this okay now?

You could use a pattern:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) grid (6, 4);
    \draw[pattern={north west lines},pattern color=red] (4,0) rectangle (5,4); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


